# Audio recording applications on Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, audio, audio-recording

I'm looking for good applications for audio recordings, that run on Linux platform.

- open-source (it's not a priority, but it's important for me)
- free (not to have to pay for it)
- simple design (not confusing one)

Audacity is the best for me yet, but its UI it's not the best... However, the usability is very good.

Comment: I was going to suggest Audacity, but you already use it :)

Comment: @Eeji There is Ardour, also, but that's too complicated. Also, bad UI, from my first point of view. Probably is more professional than Audacity, however.

Comment: Is Audacity also able to record system sound? For example if I want to record the sound directly from my computer without the external noise interfering?

Comment: Actually, I ended using Ardour, and I am happy with it (see my answer). I posted some music on my [SoundCloud profile](https://soundcloud.com/ionicabizau). :)

Answer (score 1):

### [Ardour 4](http://ardour.org/)

I'm started with Ardour 2, continued with Ardour 3 and now using Ardour 4.

Of course, when you give it the first try, things are complicated, but from my experience, I am very happy with it.

I use QJackCtl to control the jack server and as audio interface I'm using a [Scarlett-2i2](http://us.focusrite.com/usb-audio-interfaces/scarlett-2i2). After configuring the things, I have no background noise, awesome experience: it can sync in real time what I play and hear myself (there is no delay because of the audio interface I'm using).

And finally, I was saying the UI is bad. Actually it's awesome, or got improved anyway. :)

Comment: Uh, it does look overkill! I might try it to record a conference, does it have good noise reduction functions?

Comment: @Nemo Probably yes, but I didn't need such a thing *yet*. I only recorded my piano using the audio interface which was ~0 background noise. :-) It supports plugins, and there are a lot of them!!